# Query about Implicit Type casting in Java for Primitive data types

Tags: java, implicit-conversion

I HAVE BEEN LEARNING ABOUT TYPE CASTING IN JAVA AND THIS HAPPENED.

First I gave a large value to an integer variable(larger number than the range of byte data_type).
Next I created a byte variable and tried to type cast the value of first variable.
Clearly this should raise an error as the range of the byte is shorter than the value of first variable.I did this in JSHELL.

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbJW7.png)

I wish to know why java didnt give me an error and instead gave a completely different number.I didnt see any byte wraparounds as the result value is much larger.

Comment: By the way, images of text [are not well received]https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors() here.  One of the things you can do to improve this question is to edit it, and use copy-and-paste to replace the screenshot with actual text.

Comment: That is what a narrowing conversion of integer type primitives does. `myfirstnumber` is 32 bits. The cast `(byte)` copies the last 8 bits. Use of the cast says to the compiler "I know what I am doing here."

Comment: "Clearly this should raise an error" -- Java is not specified that way, from Java Language Specification [5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3-400): "*Despite the fact that overflow, underflow, or other loss of information may occur, a narrowing primitive conversion **never results in a run-time exception***" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me explain why you get 44 when casting 300 to a byte. To do so, I need to start by explaining integer representation in memory. Java, as most programming language, represents signed integers using two's complement. Simply put, every number is represented given a fixed number of binary digits (bits) `n`, where the first represents the sign and the `n-1` others represent the magnitude. For positive numbers, those `n-1` bits is simply the number in binary.

The main difference between Java's integer types is this `n`: `int`s work over `n = 32` bits whereas `byte`s use `n = 8` bits. This means that your number 300 is represented as `0000'0000'0000'0000'0000'0001'0010'1100` in memory. Now, you want to translate this number to a representation which uses only 8 bits, though you can clearly see that you need at least 10 of them (9 for the magnitude, and 1 for the sign). You will thus need to have some loss of information. Java does not consider this problem (in fact, there is no way for it to do so) and simply copies the 8 right-most bits, to give `0010'1100`. Translating this to base 10 indeed yields 44.

Notice that, if you know binary, in the conversion from `int` to `byte`, you lost a 1 in the 256 place. This may give you more intuition on why 300 - 44 = 256.

Second, let's speak about the fact Java does not give you an error. Notice first that the following code does *not* compile since an `int` can hold bigger values than a `byte` can:

```
int myfirstnumber = 100;
byte mysecondnumber = myfirstnumber;  // error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

The compiler refues to let you do a narrowing conversion without you acknowledging it; it considers that such syntax is too error-prone. However, you may sometimes want to do such a conversion. In this case, you have to show that this is indeed your intention:

```
int myfirstnumber = 100;
byte mysecondnumber = (byte)myfirstnumber;
```

In this case, the compiler thinks you know what you are doing, as [@old-dog-programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5103317/old-dog-programmer) pointed out. Now, if you don't want to loose data when doing your cast, you should make the verification that there would be an overflow yourself:

```
int myfirstnumber = 100;
byte mysecondnumber = 0;
if(Byte.MIN_VALUE <= myfirstnumber && myfirstnumber <= Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
    mysecondnumber = (byte)myfirstnumber;
} else {
    // handle the error
}
```

Comment: Did someone literally spend some of their time to remove a 3-word welcoming message at the start of my post? Don't be shocked when other people call your website unwelcoming. 
Note that welcoming messages is a [controversial question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3179), so I definitely think you should let people do whatever they want.
(And, as [Joel Marcey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/38693/joel-marcey) recalls in their thread, one of the rules of StackOverflow is to "be nice"...)